# Case expression with "if" condition?

Tags: postgresql, case

```
, CASE WHEN days > 30 and amount1 > amount3  then (amount3 *  .20)
 but if amount2 < amount1 then (amount1 *.20) else NULL end as amountcharged
```

I know the code above isn't correct. I added the "but" to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can use any number of WHEN clauses in your CASE block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `when` clause to your `case` statement, these basically work as if they were an `else if` - which from the "but if" in your question is what I think you need:

```
case when days > 30 and amount1 > amount3
     then (amount3 * .20)
     when amount2 < amount1
     then (amount1 * .20)
     else NULL
end as amountcharged
```

could be thought of as the pseudo-code logic:

```
if days > 30 and amount1 > amount3
    then (amount3 * .20)
else if amount2 < amount1
    then (amount1 * .20)
else NULL
end
```

Comment: The `ELSE NULL` is not necessary.